# JCache existe na plataforma JEE?

Tags: jee

Existe algum mecanismo de cache no JEE? JCache existe na plataforma JEE?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o **JCache <sup>([*JSR107*](https://github.com/jsr107))</sup>** esta disponível apenas a partir do JEE8, pois no 7 houve alguns problemas, conforme informado neste link do blog da Oracle:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/jcache-to-miss-java-ee-7

Se você estiver usando o 8, conforme este https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0 basta adicionar assim:

Se usa **Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Se usa **Grandle:**

```
 compile group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api', version: '1.0.0'
```

Se usa **SBT:**

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.cache" % "cache-api" % "1.0.0"
```

---

Pode baixar também o `.jar` no link:

- http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/cache/cache-api/1.0.0/cache-api-1.0.0.jar

Para atualizações acompanhe este link:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api